# How can I change the DropDown state of a user control to false when clicking outside of the control in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a user control within a C# form. This user control has a DropDown state that can be true or false. I want it to change the DropDown state to false when clicked outside of the user control.

My idea is to do something like this:

[image]

My code:

```cs
using Common.Cache;
using Common.Helpers;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Presentation.UI.Components
{
    public partial class ComboBoxSearchVendor : UserControl
    {
        private bool _IsDroppedDown = false;
        private string _SelectedValue = null;

        public ComboBoxSearchVendor()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Height = TBToggle.Height;
            Theme.DataGridView(Data);
            Data.DataSource = VendorCache.vendors;
            BringToFront();
        }

        public bool IsDroppedDown
        {
            get { return _IsDroppedDown; }
            set { _IsDroppedDown = value; }
        }

        public string SelectedValue
        {
            get { return _SelectedValue; }
            set {
                _SelectedValue = value;
                if (_SelectedValue != null)
                {
                    var vendor = VendorCache.Find(_SelectedValue);
                    if (vendor != null) TBToggle.Text = $"{vendor.Ruc} - {vendor.BusinessName}";
                }
            }
        }

        private void DropDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownAndUp();
            TBSearch.Focus();
        }

        private void DropDownAndUp()
        {
            _IsDroppedDown = !_IsDroppedDown;
            if (_IsDroppedDown)
            {
                Height = 200;
                DropDownIcon.IconChar = FontAwesome.Sharp.IconChar.ChevronUp;
                DropDownIcon.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
                TBToggle.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
            }
            else
            {
                Height = TBToggle.Height;
                DropDownIcon.IconChar = FontAwesome.Sharp.IconChar.ChevronDown;
                DropDownIcon.BackColor = Color.White;
                TBToggle.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
        }

        private void TBSearch_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            Data.DataSource = VendorCache.Filter(TBSearch.Text);
        }

        private void Data_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                DataGridViewRow Row = Data.CurrentRow;
                _SelectedValue = Row.Cells["Ruc"].Value.ToString();
                TBToggle.Text = $"{Row.Cells["Ruc"].Value} - {Row.Cells["BusinessName"].Value}";
                TBSearch.Clear();
                DropDownAndUp();   
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Helpers.Log(this, ex);
            }
        }

        private void Data_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e) { }
    }
}
```

Events are subscribed to in the user control's design file.

I trying add the `Leave` event, but not working:

```cs
private void ComboBoxSearchVendor_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!ContainsFocus)
       IsDroppedDown = false;
}
```

Comment: You want to add a mouse event change change mode when mouse is inside the control.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/input-mouse/events?view=netdesktop-7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do it from the same form, subscribe to the Leave event of the User Control.